# Can't load a DBI.so for module DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

Can't load '/3rd_party/perl/Linux/perl5.12.3_64/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/x86_64-linux/auto/DBI/DBI.so' for module DBI: /3rd_party/perl/Linux/perl5.12.3_64/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/x86_64-linux/auto/DBI/DBI.so: undefined symbol: PL_tainting at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.  at /3rd_party/perl/Linux/perl5.12.3_64/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/x86_64-linux/DBI.pm line 268 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /3rd_party/perl/Linux/perl5.12.3_64/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/x86_64-linux/DBI.pm line 268. Compilation failed in require at -e line 1. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the DBI installed by one `perl` with a different `perl`.

How you got in the situation where Perl would even get as far as it did is a mystery. Did you add paths you shouldn't to `@INC`? Start by fixing that, then install DBI using the version of Perl you are using to execute your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it turns out that the bin of 5.8.8, meanwhile I set the PERL5LIB was set to use 5.12.*...

Comment: `perlbrew` is a great way of managing multiple Perl installations on one machine.

Comment: Sorry, [link](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew). It allows you to easily install different versions of Perl, then you can switch between then using `perlbrew use version` (this shell only) or `perlbrew switch version` (change default). No need to use PERL5LIB since the default install directory is within your account.